# console app c++

Tags: c++, console

i'm new to console apps and would appreciate some pointers...

i have created a new console app and (not finished but it should be working), i selected win32 console app and then selected 'empty project'

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {

struct dude { 
    string name; 
    int age; 
} about; 

about.name = "jason"; 
about.age = 4000; 
cout << about.name << " " << about.age << endl;
}
```

The following errors i get are:

```
------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
codey.cpp
.\codey.cpp(6) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'
.\codey.cpp(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\codey.cpp(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\codey.cpp(10) : error C2039: 'name' : is not a member of 'main::dude'
        .\codey.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'main::dude'
.\codey.cpp(12) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
.\codey.cpp(12) : error C2039: 'name' : is not a member of 'main::dude'
        .\codey.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'main::dude'
.\codey.cpp(12) : error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
Test - 7 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

can somebody please tell me how i can get this to debug? what have i done wrong here?

---

**Working...**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

struct Dude { 
    std::string name; 
    int age; };

    int main(int i) 
    { 
        while(i<4000)
        {
            i++;
        using namespace std; 
        Dude jason = { "Jason", i }; 
        cout << jason.name << " is " << jason.age << " years old.\n"; 
        }

        return 0; 
    }
```

thank you all for your help :D

Comment: `int main(int i)` seems very wrong use. Here `i` is acting like `argc` which is the number of arguments passed. You are probably running the program without any, hence you get `i=0`. You can just write `int i=0;` inside `int main()`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, but it's working now. hence the "Working..." title just above the last snippet of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Dude {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  Dude jason = { "Jason", 4000 };
  cout << jason.name << " is " << jason.age << " years old.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

In no particular order:

- define your types outside of functions
- name types consistently ("Dude" here)
- provide values when initializing objects

  - I've used aggregate initialization here, you will use slightly different syntax when you write a constructor (ctor)
- the C++ stdlib is almost exclusively in the `std` namespace

  - you can place `using namespace std;` at function scope, if you like, instead of typing `std::` within that function body
- the C++ stdlib string type is from the `<string>` header
- main returns int

Fixing these problems isn't really debugging, you just need to learn the correct syntax.  Make sure you have a good book (e.g. Accelerated C++ by Koenig and Moo) and a good teacher doesn't hurt.

Comment: +1 struct About is better than struct dude from semantic point of view.

Comment: Joy: I agree, but I thought it'd cause him more confusion, so I renamed.

Comment: thank you r. pate for your help:) do you know of anybody who teaches c++? i would rather home-based rather than in school or uni

Comment: That's going to depend on where you live.  You can teach yourself by reading several books, but having someone you can go to and interact with, and go back to the next week, will be much better, even if most classes suck (Sturgeon's law).  A Q&A forum like SO can only get you so far.  The number one rule is practice, as for anything.

Answer (score 6):

The correct code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

struct dude {
  string name;
  int age;
};

int main() { 

  struct dude about;
  about.name = "jason";
  about.age = 4000;

  cout << about.name << " " << about.age << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Added the necessary includes so that it compiles. Also, as a best practise, moved type definition outside of function.

Comment: Yours is much better than mine. +1

Comment: @Martin: not really sure, your was complicate but at least pointed the  good way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Joy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760479/console-app-c/1760491#1760491), you need to use the `std` namespace:

`std::cout << about.name << " " << about.age << endl;`

Also, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe it's better if `dude` were a class?

Comment: The `class` and `struct` class-keys are identical in C++, except the first defaults to private, and the second to public, for bases and members.

Answer (score 2):

You mean how to get it to **compile**!

You forgot to put

```
using namespace std;
```

I think you should [pick up a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), spend some time reading it and come to SO like site afterwards. Just a sincere advise, no offense.